# Execute command after deployment (Capistrano and Symfony)

Tags: shell, symfony, capistrano, capistrano3

I want to execute Shell command after Capistrano deployment (*cp*) : **swift**

```
    # config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'Dometech.fr'
set :repo_url, 'ssh://git@MYIP:MYPORT/var/www/depotsGit/myproject.git/'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/dev/Myproject'

set :symfony_directory_structure, 2

set :controllers_to_clear, []

namespace :deploy do
    after "deploy:updated" , "composer:install"

    # Clear ACL only before switching version
    before "deploy:publishing" , "symfony:fixes_acl"
end

namespace :swift do
    desc 'Swift config'
    task :swift do
    on roles(:web) do
        execute :cp, '/var/www/a.php /var/www/b.php'
    end
     end
end
```

But this simple command never executed ... can you help me ?

Answer (score 4):

You defined the task, but didn't set it to run. If you add this:

```
after "deploy", "swift:swift"
```

it should be called after deploy.